# Pattern Matching for Alternate instances of Eq

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, equality, typeclass

So, I create a data type

```
data Expr a = Const a
    | Expr a :*: Expr a
```

And I define an instance for `Eq` for this data type

```
instance (Eq m) => Eq (Expr m) where
    Const a == Const b = a == b
    (a :*: b) == (c :*: d) = ((a == c) && (b == d)) || ((a == d) && (b == c))
```

This definition means that order does not matter when comparing two expressions. However, when I use pattern matching to write a function that takes `Expr`s I cannot just write

```
f (Const 1 :*: a) = ...
```

but must also write

```
f (a :*: Const 1) = ...
```

in order to catch all cases, even though if I where to compare the two using `(==)` it would return true.

Is there a way to write just one of the above to expressions and let the instance of `Eq` take care of the rest? Does pattern matching even use or require an instance of `Eq`?

Answer (score 3):

An `Eq` instance has no bearing whatsoever on pattern matches. `==` is just a library function and checks a particular property that doesn't necessarily have much to do with implementation structure, whereas pattern matches are all about deconstructing a type in its actual ADT structure.

That said, it is possible to fake something similar to what you asked, but I daresay it's not a very good idea to actually do this – doesn't scale and might lead to strange issues later on.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns #-}

matchConstFactor :: Expr a -> Maybe (a, Expr a)
matchConstFactor (Const a :*: b) = Just (a, b)
matchConstFactor (a :*: Const b) = Just (b, a)
matchConstFact _ = Nothing

pattern (:.*:) :: a -> Expr a -> Expr a
pattern a :.*: b <- (matchConstFactor -> Just (a, b))
 where a :.*: b = Const a :*: b
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to write just one of the above to expressions and let the instance of (Eq) take care of the rest?

No.

> Does pattern matching even use or require an instance of (Eq)

Only when matching against (number, character or string) literals. You can see the rules in 3.17.2 of https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#pattern-matching and note that case 7 is the only one which mentions `==`.

But you can use view patterns:

```
const1 (Const 1 :*: a) = Just a
const1 (a :*: Const 1) = Just a
const1 _ = Nothing

f (const1 -> Just a) = ...
```

This may be too ugly if you need other symmetries in other cases and I can't think of a solution for this at the moment.